# Plotting results of group_by function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by

I applied group_by function from dplyr library in R, and stored the results in a variable. however, when I try to plot the results I can only great plots that are scatter, but I am not able to create line graphs

```
site_grouped <- group_by(cells.time, SITE)
myplot <-summarize(site_grouped, mean(TTI_Vector), mean(PRB_Vecto?r))
```

any suggestions how to generate line graph for the myplot results?

Comment: it would be easy to help you if you provide a reproducible example

Comment: you don't have any plotting code in your example.